# MongoDB select query always return null with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

**Problem:**

In Mongo Db when getting a document filter by ID always returns null even though data is there.

This is my code.

```
               var listOfItems = msg.Split(',', 
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string blobUrl = listOfItems[0];
                    int type = Convert.ToInt32(listOfItems[1]);
                    string itemId = listOfItems[2];

MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(configurationRoot.GetSection("questionBankDb").Value);

Console.WriteLine("Connecting to QuestionBank");

var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("QuestionBank");
var collection = database.GetCollection<CandidateAnswer>("candidateanswer");

Console.WriteLine(itemId);

var filter = Builders<CandidateAnswer>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, itemId);

CandidateAnswer candidateAnswer =collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

And this is always returning null. This is my connection string.

```
mongodb://localhost:27018/?readPreference=nearest
```

This is my model class.

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MultimediaObject.AzFunctions.Attributes;
using System;

namespace MultimediaObject.AzFunctions.Models
{
    [BsonCollection("candidateanswer")]
    public class CandidateAnswer : Documents
    {
        public string QuestionReference { get; set; }
        public string CampaignReference { get; set; }
        public string CandidateReference { get; set; }
        public string GivenAnswer { get; set; }

        public string AnswerScrore { get; set; }

        [BsonIgnore]
        public bool IsAnswerGiven
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GivenAnswer))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnore]
        private DateTime _CreatedDate;
        public DateTime Created
        {
            get
            {
                return _CreatedDate.ToUniversalTime();
            }
            set
            {
                _CreatedDate = value;
                _CreatedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(_CreatedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
        }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnore]
        private DateTime? _ModifiedDate;
        public DateTime? Modified
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ModifiedDate.HasValue)
                {
                    return _ModifiedDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToUniversalTime();
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (value.HasValue)
                {
                    _ModifiedDate = value;
                    _ModifiedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(_ModifiedDate.GetValueOrDefault(), DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }
                else
                {
                    _ModifiedDate = null;
                }
            }
        }

        [BsonIgnore]
        public bool IsEditable { get; set; }

        public DateTime? OccurenceDate { get; set; }

        public string FirstAttempt { get; set; }
        public string SecondAttempt { get; set; }
        public string PlayerUrl { get; set; }

        [BsonIgnore]
        public bool IsSubItem { get; set; }
        public CampaignQuestions Question { get; set; }

        public bool? IsTransformedUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my document class.

```
namespace MultimediaObject.AzFunctions.Models
{
    public class Documents: IDocument
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt => DateTime.UtcNow;

        public Documents()
        {
            Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        }
    }

    public interface IDocument
    {
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(BsonObjectIdGenerator))]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        string Id { get; set; }

        DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
    }
}
```

This is a snapshot of mongo Compass

[image]

I tried a lot to find out the issue but Always it return null. Can someone help me with this issue? Thank you

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the collection and document in question from MongoDB Compass, and include the type of `itemId` (better yet its declaration and initialization). My gut feeling is that the database stores the Id as an ObjectId, but the query is being treated as a string.

Comment: does it return anything `collection.Find("{}").ToList()`?

Comment: @Llama I updated it with Compas screenshot

Comment: Correction: Mongo is not storing the Id as an ObjectId. It's just treating it as a string. I guess `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` doesn't apply here.

Comment: OP: did you ever do as dododo suggested?

Comment: @dododo That also returns empty

Comment: then you use a wrong connection string or db/coll name

Answer (score 1):

In the snapshot you provided from MongoDB Compass, the database is named "QuestionsBank".
However when obtaining the database from your code you put it as "QuestionBank" (an s is missing).

> ```
> var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("QuestionBank");
> ```

Comment: var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("QuestionsBank");